# Clarification regarding auto to constant reference

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code:

```
int a=8; 
const int &b = a;           //b is a Low-Level const
auto c = b;
```

I expected `c` to be constant int type since it has been `auto`ed to a low level const. But it is referring to `a` (which has been aliased by `b`) instead if `b` for its declaration.

`c` picks the `b`'s type only when it is used like `auto &c =b`

What I understand is only top-level const is dropped. So can someone please explain what is wrong with my understanding?

Whereas in case of a pointer, the low level const is picked by `auto`:

```
int i=9;
const int * p=&i;
auto *d=p;
*d=45;   // error: assignment of read-only location ‘* d’
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of an expression is never a reference type.  Expressions have non-reference types, and value categories.

The declaration `const int &b = a;` means:

- There will be a variable called `b`.
- The expression `b` has type `const int`.
- The expression `b` designates the same object as `a`. In other words, the names `a` and `b` both refer to the same object.
- The code `decltype(b)` resolves to `const int&`, but apart from that, you can't access the "history" of a reference. Once it's been bound, it's just a name for an int thereafter.

`auto c = X;` means that `c` is not declared as a reference; and its type is deduced from the the type of the expression `X`. If `X` happens to be the identifier of a variable, that does NOT invoke any special rules; `X` is treated as an expression in all cases.

The syntax `decltype(auto) C = X;` exists; if X is the name of a variable then this means that C is declared in the same way as X.  (If X is not the name of a variable then the behaviour depends on the value category of X too).

In your first example, `c` is deduced from the type of the expression `b` which is `const int`. As you noted, top-level const is dropped here, so `auto c` means `int c`.

In your second example, the type of the expression `p` is `const int *`. This is not a top-level const, so `auto d = p;` would be `const int * d = p;`.  In this case `auto *d` is not different to `auto d`.

Comment: So, only the reference is dropped from the expression not the pointer, hence & attached with declarator b is dropped but * attached with p is not?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus A pointer declarator declares the variable to have pointer type; a reference declarator declares the variable to have the target type and that it will be initialized by binding to some other object that may already exist

Answer (score 3):

Auto uses the template type deduction rules. The long and the short of it is that references get dropped when using `auto` (which is the reason you'll see things like `decltype(auto)` as returns for functions, as this uses a different set of rules for type deduction).

Scott Meyers goes through the rules in some detail in Item 2 of Effective Modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example b and a are linked however c becomes the constant, this is because of the const in b taking effect. The problem with the second example is that *d is type const int which cannot be modified.

Hope this helps.